# Can we prove that $F(x)=\int_0^x \sin(t^2) e^t dt, x\geq 0$ is not bounded on $[0,+\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Can we prove that $F(x)=\int_0^x \sin(t^2) e^t dt, x\geq 0$ is not bounded on $[0,+\infty)$? I believe yes. Is there any sequence that we can take to prove this? thanks

Comment: The function $$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\sin(t^2)e^t\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_{0}^{x^2}\sin(u)\frac{e^{\sqrt{u}}}{2\sqrt{u}}\,\mathrm{d}u$$ is unbounded. Indeed, $\left|F(\sqrt{n\pi})\right|\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @SangchulLee for this sequence $\sqrt{n\pi}$ you said $\left|F(\sqrt{n\pi})\right|\to\infty$, as $n\to \infty$. Sould I have to make some computation about this, or it's clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Sangchul Lee said in his comment, $|F(\sqrt{n\pi})|\to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.  This can be shown as follows: Put $a_n = \sqrt{n\pi}$. If $F(a_n)$ is bounded, then $|F(a_{n+1})-F(a_n)|$ should also be bounded.  However,

\begin{align}|F(a_{n+1})-F(a_n)| &\geq \int_{a_n}^{a_{n+1}}|\sin(t^2)|e^tdt \\
&\geq \int_{\sqrt{n\pi + \frac \pi 6 }}^{\sqrt{(n+1)\pi -\frac \pi 6  }  } |\sin(t^2)|e^tdt \\ & \geq  \frac 12 \int_{\sqrt{n\pi + \frac \pi 6 }}^{\sqrt{(n+1)\pi -\frac \pi 6}}e^tdt  \\ & \geq \frac12\exp\left(\sqrt{n\pi + \frac \pi 6} \right)\cdot \left( \sqrt{(n+1)\pi -\frac \pi 6} - \sqrt{n\pi + \frac \pi 6} \right) \\
&= \frac12 \exp\left(\sqrt{n\pi + \frac \pi 6} \right)\cdot  \frac {\frac{2}{3}\pi }{ \sqrt{(n+1)\pi -\frac \pi 6} + \sqrt{n\pi + \frac \pi 6} } 
 \end{align}

Thus $|F(a_{n+1}) - F(a_n)| \to \infty $ as $n \to \infty$; contradiction.